# Get text of enum from id

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have enumeration like below

```
enum status
{
    Active = 1
    InAvtive = 2
}
```

I have ids saved in database as like for the enumeration. Below is my code.

```
string str = "";
if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Status), StatusID))
    str = ((Status)StatusID).ToString();
else
    str = "Invalid Value";
```

I want to get values for my ID. But not working

Comment: "But not working" is *never* enough description of the behaviour you're seeing. Do you have an error at compile-time? Execution time? No errors, but incorrect results? What did you expect to see, and what did you see?

Comment: Also, please try to be clear about where the different values and variables come from, and make sure you use the same names everywhere. Your enum is called `status`, yet you type-check for `Status` (capitalized), while looking for a value for `StatusID` (is that a value fetched from the DB?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The value *is* `((Status)StatusID)`

or

if you are asking about get value based on the *name* recieved, you can use :

[Enum.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559.aspx) to achieve that.

Example:

```
(Status) Enum.Parse(typeof(Status), "Active")
```

will return `Status.Active`

Answer (score 0):

By saying you "want to get the values ..", do you mean the integer values of the Enums? If so, please try:

```
string str = "";
if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Status), StatusID))
    str = ((int)StatusID).ToString();
else
    str = "Invalid Value";
```

Comment: But this is the same code the op posted...

Comment: @Alberto No it isn't - it's still incorrect though

Comment: @DGibbs sorry you are right

Comment: This is wrong. In statement, "str = ((int)StatusID).ToString();", where did you provide Enum type ?